# WCF and custom text encoding - messy business

Tags: wcf, character-encoding, diacritics, custom-binding

I have a really weird WCF problem here...

We're connecting to a crappy third-party web service; it was a nightmare to even get it going, we had to create a custom WCF binding since those guys decided to use "ISO-8859-1" as their text encoding (instead of UTF-8 like everyone else on the web), and the other settings were messy, too - and not documented anywhere, of course...

It's been working ok for a while now, but suddenly, some of our data coming back in mangled up. We expect to get back names of places, and being in Switzerland, some of those have German umlauts in them. But for the past two or three months, we suddenly get back

```
HÃ¼nibach
```

instead of the proper

```
Hünibach
```

So the ü (u umlaut) is mangled.

No problem, I figured they finally switched to UTF-8, and I changed my custom binding to use UTF-8 as its text encoder instead of ISO-8859-1 - but no luck - no I'm getting:

> EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
>   The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Basic'.

What the f????? The service is protected by a username/password which we pass in using the `ClientCredentials` of WCF. Seems that changing the text encoding somehow messes up the credentials !?!?! Weird.....

OK - back to ISO-8859-1, and I just tried to interpret the response payload as UTF-8 - again no luck :-(  Tried with UTF-16, UTF-32, UTF-7 even, Unicode, BigEndianUnicode - all to no avail.

So how on earth do I get back my proper umlauts, and still be able to call that bloody service... works just fine in SoapUI, btw.....

Any ideas?? I'm desperately grasping at any straws you might throw me!!

Comment: I have no idea why this happens but you can try to get raw messages (bytes) and try to decode them by UTF-8, Latin 1 and whatever else to check how the payload changes. If you use plain HTTP you can use Fiddler to get messages. Other idea is that generally receiving responses in one encoding doesn't meant the server expects requests in the same encoding.

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the data you are getting back and see what numeric codes they are using to represent it.  Umlaut is one of those characters in 8859-1 that shares code with other characters.

See second para in - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C#Typography

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I finally figured out what the trouble was.

For some reason, changing the sample `CustomTextEncoder` (provided by Microsoft in the WCF & WF samples) to use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 **doesn't work**.

On the other hand, ripping out the custom text encoder from my custom binding and just using the standard `TextMessageEncoder` that WCF provides from the get go (which uses UTF-8 by default) **did work**.

Don't ask me why.... that's just the facts I found.....